# Reassigning SASS variable inside javascript function, similar to setProperty used for CSS variables?

Tags: javascript, css, sass

In css i can declare variable:

```
:root {
  --main-bg-color: pink;
}
```

And then using javascript to reassign value:

```
document.body.style.setProperty('--main-bg-color', '#5A8795')
```

---

How to make something similar with Sass variables?

```
$main-bg-color: pink;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is unfortunately not possible. You can however achieve what you want by using this technique. And then edit it in the final step via Js.

```
$var: /**/;

--variable: #{$var};
```

Hope this is at least a little helpful ;'D

Comment: @Qui-GonJinn, Yeah! Not that long ago, that I actually first stumbled upon this.

Answer (score 1):

@Simplicius is right, You can't. Because SASS is a CSS preprocessor, that means that all SASS specific information disapears when you compile it to CSS.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
$main: pink;

:root {
  --main: #{$main}
}
```